# OpenNLP - Named Entity Recognition - dd.mm.yyyy Date format in txt file for .bin model training

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

My txt file for model training has date tags in  dd.mm.yyyy  format. But when I try to use the trained .bin file, the dates are not extracted as they should. My txt tagged file is written one sentence in line. I was wondering maybe the format, and the fullstops in this date format make a difficulty for the model to learn. In the official OpenNLP documentation I can see there is a bin file with date extraction, but I can't see the txt file containing the tags.

I tried to open this bin as a txt format but I read in Stack Overflow that I can't do that.

[How can I view the content of a .bin file in opennlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140492/how-can-i-view-the-content-of-a-bin-file-in-opennlp)

Comment: If the dates in your text are consistently formatted why not just use a regular expression?

Comment: @polm23 we actually tried that solution and it works ty